# Check bad sector location

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, bad-sectors, check-disk

Doing a checkdisk on one of my partition in Windows XP, it reports that there is 4KB in bad sectors.

How can I know if this bad sector belongs to a file/folder or not, and if yes which file/folder it is so I can avoid accessing it?

Comment: If you have a bad sector on disk, backup your data and move to another disk. Where there are few of them, soon more will be.. Try to boot to some linux distribution http://www.sysresccd.org/Download an run command `badblocks -svn /dev/sda` / /dev/sda in case you have just one disk, you can find your disks designation by running `fdisk -l`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using contain **nfi.exe** tool which is included in Win2K OEM support tools to identify the file that occupies a particular sector:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/win2000srv/utility/3.0/nt45/en-us/oem3sr2.zip

Nfi.exe also works on Win XP and 2003. More Info [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/253066/en-us). This is an example of output I've made on my W7 machine. Run this tool from CMD. If no switches are added - help will appear.

Use ***C:\nfi.exe C: >C:\output.txt*** to save results and search for specific sectors later.
Good Luck!

[image]

Comment: Why do the zeroes look so weird?